# Win 8 hibernation file format?

Tags: parsing, windows-8, file-format, hibernation

I am writing a C#/C++ program which will decompress win8 hibernation file. However, I haven't found hiberfil.sys format for new OS.

Is there any description of Win8 hiberfil.sys file format to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

That file is not new to Win 8.  However, I'm not sure whether the format has changed over time.  In any case, here's a [link to a PDF from 2008](http://msuiche.net/con/bhusa2008/Windows_hibernation_file_for_fun_%27n%27_profit-0.6.pdf) that describes the file and some tools.

Comment: It is not new, but it has different format, than for Win7 and previous fles.

Comment: @Alex You might try contacting the author of the document linked above:  Matthieue Suiche (matt[at]msuiche.net).  He might be able to point you to some current info.

Comment: @Alex - Have you found anything?

Comment: @qdot unfortunately, no.